# JS: how to get resulting value out of its function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I process a string, and want to get the end result out of the function so the next function can reuse it. Basically, I currently approach is such:

```
function pre_processing(str){
 str = str.replace(/\d/g, ""); // delete all digit (a simplier example than my code)
 return str;
}
function post_processing(){ 
 // do processing n⁰2 on var str
}
pre_processing("w0rd2");
console.log(str) // fails! Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined 
post_processing(str); // fails, haven't input
```

This doesn't works. **What does I do wrong ?** is it a `return` not done right, or related to asynchroneous JS ? Other ? **2. How to do it right ?**

Full JS code there : **http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/CYwD3/7/** (I made it as simple as possible)

Comment: I don't think you can reverse the scope -- if a variable is created inside a function, it won't be accessible outside of the function.

Comment: I tried in the root to first create `var str = "";` then `function name(){ ...; return str; }`. This doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "pre_processing" function returns a string, but you're paying no attention to the return value:

```
var str = pre_processing("w0rd2");
```

Now you have a variable called "str" *outside* the functions.

Of course you can just apply the second function directly to the result of the first:

```
console.log( post_processing( pre_processing("w0rd2") ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

The function then equals that return value, so:

```
var str = pre_processing("w0rd2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign it to a var when it returns, because the function has now assumes the value of the evaluation, so

```
var newStr = pre_processing("w0rd2");
```

Also, shorten your function up with this

```
return str.replace(/\d/g,"");
```

instead of `str = str.replace(/\d/g,""); return str;`

and finally

```
var newStr = post_processing(newStr);
```